# Update error für OpenSuse 12.3 for "libsolv-tools-0.3.2-2.14.1"

Tags: linux, updates, opensuse, zypper

I seem to have broken my update system on OpenSuSe 12.3. Whenever I try to update I get this message:

```
( 1/23) Installing: libsolv-tools-0.3.2-2.14.1 .....................................[error]
Installation of libsolv-tools-0.3.2-2.14.1 failed:
(with --nodeps --force) Error: Subprocess failed. Error: RPM failed: error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/bin/dumpsolv: cpio: rename failed - Input/output error
error: libsolv-tools-0.3.2-2.14.1.x86_64: install failed
error: libsolv-tools-0.3.2-2.10.1.x86_64: erase skipped


Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i] (a):
```

When looking at for program dumpsolv in `/usr/bin`, I get this:

```
# ls | grep "dumpsolv"
dumpsolv
dumpsolv;528134c9
dumpsolv;528134d2
dumpsolv;528134da
dumpsolv;528134ec
dumpsolv;5281350e
dumpsolv;52813523
dumpsolv;52828c89
dumpsolv;52880d1a
dumpsolv;52880d44...
```

followed by many more lines like this. One for every failed installation of `libsolv-tools-0.3.2-2.14.1`

When looking at dumpsolv I get these errors:

```
# stat /usr/bin/dumpsolv
stat: cannot stat ‘/usr/bin/dumpsolv’: Input/output error
```

and (of cause)

```
# lsattr /usr/bin/dumpsolv
lsattr: Input/output error while trying to stat /usr/bin/dumpsolv
```

I already tried out the following commands:

```
zypper ve
rpm --rebuilddb
```

And this:
https://joshua.hoblitt.com/rtfm/2013/05/dealing_with_rpm_cpio_rename_package_installupdate_errors/

Here is the tool that is causing the update issue:
http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/opensuse/updates/12.3/x86_64/libsolv-tools-0.3.2-2.14.1.x86_64.html

And my uname

```
# uname -a
Linux linux-3hbw.site 3.7.10-1.16-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 31 20:21:23 UTC 2013 (97c14ba) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am really at a loss here. I already posted in there forums, but without any luck, they seem to be as puzzled as I am:

- http://www.opensuse-forum.de/update-error-f%C3%BCr-opensuse-12-3-f%C3%BCr-libsolv-tools-0-3-2-2-14-1-software-installieren-aktualisieren/allgemeines-f17/t9540-f55/
- http://www.unixboard.de/vb3/showthread.php?54758-Update-error-f%FCr-OpenSuse-12-3-f%FCr-quot-libsolv-tools-0-3-2-2-14-1-quot

Also, I cannot reinstall the currently installed `libsolv-tools`, as I get the same error that I get when trying to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it, It was a problem with my file-system. Here is what I did:

First I saw that `stat` returned an input/output error. That seemed strange to me, so I checked the whole directory:

```
# stat /usr/bin/* | grep "Input/output error"
```

And got a whole list of errors. Thus I knew that it was not a problem with dumpsolv, but rather something with a bit more impact. This lead me to search the web and I found out that it could in fact be an error in the file-system.
To repair the root file-system in OpenSuse they offer some really great advice:
http://www.novell.com/documentation/suse91/suselinux-adminguide/html/ch12s05.html

Thus I booted up the installation-DVD, canceled the installation to get my command-prompt as root and used `e2fsck` on my root partition, which is `/dev/sdb1` like so:

```
# e2fsck /dev/sdb1
```

After this I got a really long list of different inode errors, which I read carefully and fixed whatever could be fixed (which was everything, I guess). After this I rebooted my system from harddrive and the problem was solved. I can install my updates and everything is running fine now.

But if you try this: be extremely careful! You are messing with your root partition here and you should read everything it tells you and verify it. Best have a second computer running to check in case you are not sure about something. If you get a bad superblock (which I did not have) you can use `dumpe2fs <partition>` in order to see which block it is and then use `e2fsck -b <block> <partition>` to restore the file-system from backup.

Everything is explained well in the link I posted above plus there are a lot of websites on the internet containing information about the use of `e2fsck` and `dumpe2fs`, you should consult these first if you have any doubts.

I do hope that this can help someone else.